# Undefined method with `respond_with`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

EDIT: I would like to know why Ruby/Rails is deciding to look for a function called `word_list_url` in my controller. Normally everything makes sense as to why it's done in RoR, but this doesn't make sense to me.

I'm trying to `respond_with` a model object in one of my controller functions like so:

```
def create
   @word_list = WordList.new(params[:word_list])
   @word_list.key = randomKey
   if @word_list.title == nil then @word_list.title = "No Title"
   end
   if @word_list.words == nil then @word_list.words = "Empty"
   end
   @word_list.save
   respond_with @word_list
end
```

Then I'm calling the API like so:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"New Word List", "words":"Words\nFor\nThe\nWord\nList"}' http://localhost:3000/create.json
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `word_list_url' for #<WordListsController:0x007fb34c95ca98>):
  app/controllers/word_lists_controller.rb:42:in `create'
```

However, this is the model:

```
class WordList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :key, :title, :words
end
```

Where is it getting the "method `word_list_url`" from? I'm not fully sure what is going on. I have my `respond_to`:

```
respond_to :json, :xml
```

What is going on here? If I use `render` instead of `respond_with`, everything works just fine.

---

Currently, in other functions, `respond_with` is working just fine. For example:

```
  def show
    lists = WordList.where(:key => params[:id].upcase)
    if lists.length > 0 then @word_list = lists.first
    elsif numberValue(params[:id]).between?(0, WordList.count) then @word_list = WordList.find(params[:id])
    end
    respond_with(@word_list)
  end
```

---

Routes:

```
create POST   /create(.:format) word_lists#create
update PUT    /update(.:format) word_lists#update
       GET    /:id(.:format)    word_lists#show
```

Comment: can you include your routes in your question?

Answer (score 1):

if you look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html, you'll see that having support for xml format expands to

```
format.xml { render :xml => @word_list, :status => :created, :location => @word_list }
```

I think `:location` uses `url_for` which may cause your error. try

```
respond_with @word_list do |format|
  format.xml { render :xml => @word_list, :status => :created }
end
```

Comment: Why do I need to render the `@word_list` if I'm already using `respond_with`? I'm using a straight `respond_with` in other functions of mine. I'll post an example.

Comment: after more testing, finally figured out that it's because you are in the create action which passes a location option as I stated above.  The example you posted uses the show action.

Comment: Okay. But when I read the docs, it states that the `do |format|` block is the same as just `respond_with(@object)`. While doing the individual formats works, I don't understand why its having the issue, considering that dropping `:xml` support doesn't prevent the issue.

Comment: my bad, in the docs, the example uses xml and http requests only.  since you're requesting for json format, it most probably uses the same format as the xml one

Comment: But what I'm pointing out is that the docs say the `do |format|` is the same, but it shows that it has something called `:location`, which you've mentioned. What is that? I can't seem to find what `:location` is.

Comment: Okay. So, if I wanted to support location, what would I need?

Comment: you need to manually set the `location` to point to the route you use. `respond_with(@word_list, :location => path_to_word_list)`

Comment: Otherwise it would check my WordList model for a function called `word_list_url`?

Comment: no it's not checking the model. it's using the class of the object to build the url. by convention that's `word_list_url(@word_list)` which came from the `WordList`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25817/discussion-between-rileye-and-jvnill)